# Etherminer has stopped working

Tags: windows, mining-pools, ethminer

> ethminer.exe -G -F
>   poolurl/mywallet

it stops working at `Grabbing DAG for #deb.`

Mining is impossible...

Comment: Maybe your DAG is corrupted. Have you tried deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like its running out of memory and failing.  You will need at least a 4gb memory graphics card to successfully participate in mining.  If you point to a mining pool it will help.